# SmartTarget Dynamic filter not working

Tags: smarttarget

I have set up a promotion where the content selection is filtered based on a component field value, which is a *interest* text field selected from a (non-keyword) list with 3 possible values; Games, Girls and Golf. If select a specific fixed value (like **Golf**), the filter works OK and SmartTarget returns my promotion with only Golf related items back. If however, I select a dynamic value, based on an *Interest* trigger I have set up SmartTarget does not return the promotion or any items, even though I can see that the trigger value is set correctly to **Golf** in the URL passed through to Fredhopper.

Is there any way I can debug this in Fredhopper to see what is going wrong?

UPDATE: Possibly related to this, I notice that in the dropdown in the SmartTarget GUI to select a filter value, for static values I get multiple entries for the same value (for example there are two entries for Golf) it seems that there is one per piece of content published linked to that value. If I select different identical values, I get different content items back - in each case a single item. Its almost as if it is indexing a different underlying value each time with the same display name.

UPDATE 2: I changed my schema to be a plain text field, republished all the content and did a reindex. Now my promotion returns content items matching the Golf dynamic filter value, but also some other seemingly randomly selected items (from Girls and Games). If I use a static filter value of Golf, I get exactly the right items. It seems to me that as well as the indexing process not really working for list schema fields, something is FUBAR in the dynamic filtering.

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot of information in your question that I cannot answer without looking at the system itself.

But you did ask how you can troubleshoot it. I would start by looking at the query in the SmartTarget logs and compare it to the query you get by using the Preview feature in Fredhopper.

As for having multiple entries in the list, is it possible that they are for different Publications?

Comment: When I add a trigger for interest = Golf in the Preview feature I get all results returned (in the SmartTarget meta promotion) - it doesn't seem to have any effect. I experience the same when I try to add a Region trigger.

Comment: Just to be clear: the trigger will not filter the normal items, only the ones returned by the Promotion. The ones you care about should be shown with a different background color and indented under the Promotion.